# Global filter For all tables

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an application with more than 100 tables
I would like to apply a global filter on all tables as all tables have the same field name "IsDeleted" 
so i would like to always include IsDeleted = false to all queries

Currently i use `entity.HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);` in every table model builder
Is there is a way to do it once somewhere?

PS: In my application i have 5 Context, is there is away to write maybe an extension method to apply this filter on all of them .

Comment: I'm sure you tried something. Please show your efforts to make more explicit where you need help.

Comment: I wrote what i tried, i added entity.HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted) in every OnModelCreating for every table, so in total more than 100 times

Comment: Create a BaseRepository and create a method (GetDefaultFilter) to handle this common filter. Add your filter condition as an Expression object and append to Query.  Egs - Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter

Comment: Sure, but did you try to achieve what you ask here? I'm in no way trying to nag you, but own efforts tend to clarify lack of background information that your question clearly suffers from. Like, do your classes implement a common interface or inherit from a base class? Also, IMO using soft deletes in combination with EF is a total failure, because EF translates required relationships as inner joins. Just think of what that does to query results when related entities are "deleted" while you obviously expect to see their non-"deleted" children!

Comment: Addition: soft delete with global query filters, that is.